# Vagrant::Errors::NetworkCollision: The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network

Tags: networking, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm using vagrant with multiple machine, it's ever worked normally, but then it just doesn't work again.

My part of Vagrantfile that defining the network:

```
config.vm.define "app" do |layer| 
    layer.vm.provision "chef_solo", id:"chef" do |chef|
         .....
    end

    # Forward port 80 so we can see our work
    layer.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 9999
    layer.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"
  end
```

It's a standar configuration and I only have that vm. But when I tried to `vagrant up`, it shows error:

```
Vagrant::Errors::NetworkCollision: The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently my office just changed the network configuration. By changing 10.10.10.10. to other blok (e.g 10.0.0.100), it workedagain. Sorry.