# New IP Breaks VirtualBox and Homestead Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I had to replace my router which in turn gave my dev box a new IP address and has since broken my local VirtualBox with a Homestead/Vagrant Laravel image.  Here's the error that I'm getting when running vagrant up or restore or --provision:

==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Changed router base IP address map from the factory assigned 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.10.1 to get back to the same map from previous router of 192.168.10.1.
2. Reserved an IP address of 192.168.10.10 on my router and assigned it to my machine's mac address.

test results:  same error of host network collision

3. Changed router base IP address map to 10.10.10.1
4. Reserved an IP address of 10.10.10.10 on my router and assigned it to my machine's mac address.
5. Replaced all 192.168.10.10 IP addresses in my project (homestead.yaml, homestead.rb, etc.) with 10.10.10.10
6. Updated my hosts file to point 10.10.10.10 to mysite.app

test results:  same error of host network collision

7. Time Machine restored my entire machine image to a week ago

test results:  same error of host network collision

8. Time Machine restored my entire machine image to today's backup
9. Reset router and all project files back to 192.168.10.10
10. Turned off Wifi (no network connection, no local IP address)
11. Run vagrant up
12. Confirmed host file maps 192.168.10.10 to mysite.app

test results:  vagrant scripts run successfully, no error messages however I can only access the resulting local nginx site through http://192.168.10.10 and not http://mysite.app

13. Turn wifi back on (assigned IP is now 192.168.10.10)

results:  can't access local nginx site at all, either via http://192.168.10.10 or http://mysite.app

14. Installed a fresh new laravel project and corresponding fresh new homestead box.  Running vagrant up returns the same error message.
15. Rebooted many times during this process, same problems.
16. Deleted and reinstalled VirtualBox, same problem.

My initial diagnosis is that this has nothing to do with Laravel, nor homestead but is most likely caused by a VirtualBox setting or network connection.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

[similar problem posted to laracast forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-up-the-specified-host-network-collides-with-a-non-hostonly-network)

[same error message on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051239/vagranterrorsnetworkcollision-the-specified-host-network-collides-with-a-no)

Comment: I have (and keep having) the same issue when I switch from VM between vmware and virtual box, usually restarting the OS (mac in my case) solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

You've proven

```
vagrant up --provision
```

This recharges your yaml file

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/provision.html

Comment: Tried this:  vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.